# How can I get the term id after using taxonomy_save_term?

Tags: drupal-6

```
$term = array(
  'vid' => 1, // Voacabulary ID
  'name' => $data[3], // Term Name 
  'parent' => 181, // (Optional) Term ID of a parent term  
 );
 taxonomy_save_term($term);
```

How do I get the term id that was just added?

Answer (score 0):

You can get term id by echo $term->tid

Thanks,
Snehal